# Custom ActionFilter resolving DI

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using `Microsoft Unity (DI)` container to `inject my project dependencies.` 
I am using property dependency injection (DI) in one of my `custom action filter` using attribute.

**Example:**

```
public class SumCheck : ActionFilterAttribute
{ 
    [Dependency]
    public TestContext _context { get; set;}

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        /* code */
    }
}
```

Can i resolve dependency inside `OnActionExecuting?` So that whenever `OnActionExecuting` gets called, it resolves (gets new) instance of the class that implement `ITestContext`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915192/property-injection-on-attributes

Comment: See [Constructor Dependency Injection WebApi Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352680/constructor-dependency-injection-webapi-attributes/28365933#28365933) for an example of what @Steven is referring to.